# Is this "ever" grammatical here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

> 1: *I walked up and asked, “What is the matter?” and I regret **ever** doing that.*<sup>1</sup>
> 2: *You can see by the situation I'm in that I regret **ever** using drugs.*<sup>2</sup>

Is this *ever* grammatical here?

[OxfordDictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ever) includes the definitions ***at any time*** and ***at all times; always***. In the cited usages, does it mean *"I [now] regret having done [the regretted thing] **at any time in the past**"?* That seems unlikely in the context of #1, since the action could obviously only have happened at one specific time.

Or does it mean *"I **always regret / have always regretted** doing it"?* In which case, is the regret implied to have started ***immediately after I did it**?* That seems unlikely in the context of #2, since presumably the speaker repeatedly used drugs after the first time.

---

<sub>1. [That a Man Can Stand: The Evolution of a Nation](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VCUqAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA416&dq=%22and%20I%20regret%20ever%20doing%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ltueU8LdCYeVPOHBgfAN&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22and%20I%20regret%20ever%20doing%20that%22&f=false)</sub>

<sub>2. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20regret%20ever%20using%20drugs%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)</sub>

Comment: @BobRodes - I agree the question could use some [additional information](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439). (Where is this quote from? Why is the _ever_ a source of confusion?) That said, I'm not sure that those definitions of _ever_ answer or clear up the problem. (But maybe that was your point? Without additional information, it's hard to tell what's really being asked.)

Comment: @BobRodes I would suggest you to move with such passive-aggressive comments to ELU. To be honest, I do know what _ever_ means (very likely OP knows it as well), but its usage in such a sentence and moreover in the middle of it is IMHO rather unsual and while I get the meaning, I'm far from understanding what is behind it gramatically. So +1 for the question.

Comment: I still think the question is hard to answer without a source. [I can't find one](https://www.google.com/search?q="I+repented+ever+doing+this+all+by+myself"&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t). This could be a request for proofreading, or maybe it asks about an archaic quote, or it could even be typo (perhaps the original was supposed to say _even_, not _ever_). I think more information is needed before this can be properly answered.

Comment: As you will. However, googling "definition ever", looking at the first link, and evaluating the definitions answered the question for me. That's why I lmgtfy'd the OP. I suppose his putting a note on my answer to another of his questions that pretty clearly showed that he didn't go to the trouble of reading it had something to do with it as well. I'm getting that "help vampire" feeling, you know? Maybe IT forums are stricter about this, but it seems to me that we also expect someone to at least try to answer a question for himself before asking here.

Comment: @tohecz I'm sorry, but this looks simple to me.  The meaning is "I was sorry that I had ever decided to do this for myself."  The meaning "at any time" from the dictionary clearly applies, with the converse "I wished that I had not at any time (never) decided to do this for myself."  Seems clear to me that the OP didn't even bother to look up the word in the dictionary, so I actively-aggressively suggested that he start participating in his own edification to the extent that he's able.  :)

Comment: @J.R.: I disagree with your unilateral closevote, and have voted to reopen. It's true that idiomatically one would be much more likely to say [*"I **regret** ever having {done something}"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+regret+ever+having%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) rather than [*"I **repent** ever having {done it}"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+repent+ever+having%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but that's incidental. And Bob notwithstanding, I can see how this use of ***ever*** might seem "unusual" to a learner, so it's a reasonable question.

Comment: ...I've also [raised the issue on meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/). Not really so much in order to criticize your action - rather to establish what the general consensus is regarding mods taking actions which could reasonably have been taken by ordinary users *if at least 5 of them agree, and if they were given sufficient time to evaluate the matter*, on issues which aren't as pressing as spam, offensive posts, etc.

Comment: @BobRodes: I think we should assume the OP isn't having a problem *understanding* the cited text. But syntactically it seems at least *slightly* unusual, and with the best will in the world one might still fail to easily identify a corresponding usage in a dictionary, or an explanation of how exactly it differs from *"I repented **always** doing it"*, or why *"I repented **at any time** doing it"* would probably never be accepted as "grammatical" (they being the two most likely "synonyms" you'd find in a dictionary).

Comment: Why is this question Community Wiki, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1):

It is very correct and quite common. I think the best way to explain it is to paraphrase its meaning:

It implies (in your example at least):

> "[I regret] that it even occurred to me to do such a thing"

or more dramatically

> "I rue the moment I decided to do such a thing (in the first place)"

or in a roundabout way:

> "I wish I'd never done such-and-such"

Answer (score 0):

The 'ever' in your examples is grammatical. It's used to make an expression more emphatic.